# Ring epimorphisms, and epimorphism in the category of small preadditive cats

Tags: ct.category-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra

This question is related to [this other question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/187961/exactness-of-an-additive-left-kan-extension) I have asked some time ago. Let $R$ and $S$ be two rings and let $\phi:R\to S$ be a ring homomorphism.

It is well-known that $\phi$ is an epimorphism in the category of rings if and only if the counit of the adjunction $(-\otimes_R{}_RS_S,-\otimes_S{}_SS_R)$ (where the structures of left or right $R$-module on $S$ are induced using $\phi$), is a natural isomorphism. I usually denote the adjunction described above by $(\phi_!,\phi^*)$, here $\phi^*:Mod(S)\to Mod(R)$ is a restriction of scalars, while $\phi_!:Mod(R)\to Mod(S)$ is extension of scalars.

Now, since $\phi_!$ is left adjoint, we can consider its restriction to the respective categories of finitely presented modules, obtaining a new functor $\Phi:=(\phi_!)_{mod(R)}:mod(R)\to mod(S)$, between the two preadditive categories $mod (R) $ and $mod (S)$. Of course, this new functor induces extension and restriction of scalars:
$$\Phi_!:((mod (R))^{op},Ab)\rightleftarrows ((mod (S))^{op},Ab):\Phi^*$$
and we can ask under which conditions the counit $\Phi_!\Phi^*\to id$ is an isomorphism. This is probably the same as saying that $\Phi$ is an epimorphism in the category of preadditive small categories (with additive functors as morphisms).

My question is: Can we characterize those $\phi$ for which $\Phi_!\Phi^*\to id$ is an isomorphism? Is this equivalent to $\phi_!\phi^*\to id$ being an isomorphism, so equivalent to say that $\phi$ is a ring epimorphism, or is it a genuinely stronger condition?

Comment: This might be a silly/easy question, but if $\phi:R\to S$ is a ring epimorphism and $M$ is a finitely presented $S$-module, do you know whether there is always a finitely presented $R$-module $N$ such that $M\cong N\otimes_RS$ (or at least $M$ is a direct summand of $N\otimes_RS$)? It's true when $\phi$ is a surjection.

Comment: So you are asking whether $\Phi$ in my question is surjective on objects, provided $\phi$ is an epimorphism. I do not know if this is true but I do not see any easy counterexample right now.

Comment: Yes. I wondered if there might be some functor on f.p. $S$-modules that was zero on $N\otimes_RS$ for all f.p. $R$-modules $N$. If that were the case, then it would show that $\Phi_!\Phi^*\to\text{id}$ need not be an isomorphism.

Comment: It seems that the answer to my question is "yes" (if it had been "no" then it would have implied the existence of examples where $\Phi_!\Phi^*\to\text{id}$ is not an isomorphism).

Comment: Your question of whether $\Phi_!\Phi^*\to\text{id}$ must be an isomorphism is equivalent to asking whether $\Phi^*$ must be fully faithful. It follows from my last comment that it's faithful.

Comment: @JeremyRickard, Thanks for your comments! Since there is a bounty ending tomorrow, if you want to post your partial answer with some details, I will accept it before tomorrow. Then it will be possible to edit. Also, I think that to have this partial answer could help others to give a complete answer.

Comment: There is no restriction of scalars for finitely presented modules.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, I do not understand your comment. The functor $\Phi$ is clearly defined as the restriction  of $\phi_!$. Then $\Phi^*$ is defined sending a functor $F:\mathrm{mod}(S)^{op}\to \mathrm{Ab}$ to $F\circ \Phi$. Finally $\Phi_!$ is the additive left Kan extension along $\Phi$, you can construct it "explicitly" using tensor product of bifunctors.